# How to fix yum error: No module named CElementTree?

Tags: centos, python, yum

I've the following problem with yum:

```
$ yum
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named cElementTree

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.4.3 (#1, Feb 22 2012, 16:06:13) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://wiki.linux.duke.edu/YumFaq
```

My OS: CentOS release 5.8 (Final)

When trying to install python-elementtree manually from RPM package, it gives the following error:

```
$ sudo rpm -i http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/os/i386/CentOS/python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.i386.rpm
package python-elementtree-1.2.6-7.el4.rf.i386 (which is newer than python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.i386) is already installed
$ sudo rpm -i http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/os/i386/CentOS/python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.i386.rpm
```

Related links:

- http://www.rickrodriguezjr.com/wordpress/archives/183
- http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=936132
- http://www.clearfoundation.com/component/option,com_kunena/Itemid,232/catid,26/func,view/id,45278/
- http://pingd.org/2012/no-module-named-celementtree-yum-update-error.html
- http://forums.contribs.org/index.php?topic=49189.0
- http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=3401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Try to download and install `python-elementtree` manually:

#### x86_64

```
wget http://mirrors.usc.edu/pub/linux/distributions/centos/5.8/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh python-elementtree-*.rpm
```

#### i386

```
wget http://mirrors.usc.edu/pub/linux/distributions/centos/5.8/os/i386/CentOS/python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.i386.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh python-elementtree-*.rpm
```

### Troubleshooting

#### Error: 'package python-elementtree-1.2.6-7.el4.rf.i386 (which is newer than python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.i386) is already installed' or similar

Try to replace the package, even it's installed by:

```
sudo rpm -iv --replacepkgs python-elementtree-*.rpm
```

or:

```
sudo rpm -iv --replacefiles python-elementtree-*.rpm
```

or finally:

```
sudo rpm -iv --force python-elementtree-*.rpm
```

See: [--replacepkgs: Install the Package Even If Already Installed](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-install-additional-options.html)

Comment: The "proper" option for rpm in this case is `--oldpackage` to allow for a downgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, is python-elementtree still installed? The cEleementTree module should live in `/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/cElementTree.so` (/usr/lib/... on 32bit systems). Does that file still exist?

If the package is missing, you can resintall it with rpm:

x86_64:

```
rpm -i http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.x86_64.rpm
```

i386:

```
rpm -i http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/os/i386/CentOS/python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.i386.rpm
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work:
 package python-elementtree-1.2.6-7.el4.rf.i386 (which is newer than python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.i386) is already installed

Comment: I've posted some answer to my question, but it doesn't work either (but could help for other).

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, actually this command did work: sudo rpm -iv --force python-elementtree-*.rpm